# How to Open and Close Angular-UI popovers programmatically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, popover, angular-ui-bootstrap

I need to create popovers that gets its content from the server.

So I created the following directive:

```
.directive('myPopover', [myService, function ($myService) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            transclude: true,
            template: '<a href="" ng-click="wordClicked()" class="highlight" popover-trigger="manual" popover="Adequately good for the circumstances" popover-title="good enough " popover-placement="bottom" ng-transclude></a>',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.wordClicked = function () {
                    if ( POPUP IS NOT SHOWING ){
                        var message = myService.getMessage({key: element.text()},
                            function () {
                                    console.info("NEED TO SHOW POPOVER WITH "+ message);
                                });
                    }
                    else {
                        console.info("NEED TO CLOSE POPOVER");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }]);
```

And inside getMessage success method I need to make the popover to show. 
The [documentation](http://angular-ui.github.io/) does not give any indication for that though I found comment made
By Luthur [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/590) it seems like there is a `popover-trigger="manual"` option. 
Could not find a way to trigger it programmatically

**Update:**
I tried to follow *Mosho* advice but I am having troubles creating a popover with the custom event trigger.

see [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/NZm3gAGSJewLJyRTaee5?p=preview)

Thanks!

Comment: i'm little change your [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/JrudQs6m93QYbOh4LYOu?p=preview) and all work fine

Answer (score 8):

First, if you haven't already looked, here are the sources for tooltips and popovers:

[tooltip.js](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/tooltip/tooltip.js)

[popover.js](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/popover/popover.js)

You can add custom triggers. Popovers use the `$tooltip` provider:

```
.directive( 'popover', [ '$tooltip', function ( $tooltip ) {
  return $tooltip( 'popover', 'popover', 'click' );
}]);
```

Where the `$tooltip`'s provider `$get` method, used to make new `tooltip`'s, is defined here:

```
 this.$get = [ '$window', '$compile', '$timeout', '$parse', '$document', '$position', '$interpolate', function ( $window, $compile, $timeout, $parse, $document, $position, $interpolate ) {
    return function $tooltip ( type, prefix, defaultTriggerShow ) {...}
```

The `$tooltip` provider has this method: (triggerMap is the 3 triggers that are defined in the `$tooltip` provider out of the box.

```
   /**
   * This allows you to extend the set of trigger mappings available. E.g.:
   *
   *   $tooltipProvider.setTriggers({'openTrigger': 'closeTrigger'});
   */
  this.setTriggers = function setTriggers ( triggers ) {
    angular.extend( triggerMap, triggers );
  };
```

You can use it in a config block, like this:

```
myApp.config(['$tooltipProvider', function ( $tooltipProvider ) {
  $tooltipProvider.setTriggers({'openTrigger': 'closeTrigger'}) ;
}]);
```

Then, you can create a new popover directive like this:

```
.directive('myPopover', ['$tooltip', function ( $tooltip ) {
  return $tooltip( 'myPopover', 'myPopover', 'openTrigger' );
}]);
```

And triggering the popover would then be as simple as `element.triggerHandler( 'openTrigger' )` (or `closeTrigger`) where `element` is the popover.

Comment: thanks for the elaborated answer. I looked at the tooltip code and was able to add my custom triggers. I was not able to create a popover with my trigger as you suggested. See update in post.

Answer (score 6):

I extended the popover directive in order to add an attribute "pop-show" which accepts a boolean:

```
angular.module('app', [ 'ui.bootstrap' ])
  .directive( 'popPopup', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      replace: true,
      scope: { title: '@', content: '@', placement: '@', animation: '&', isOpen: '&' },
      templateUrl: 'template/popover/popover.html'
    };
  })

  .directive('pop', function pop ($tooltip, $timeout) {
    var tooltip = $tooltip('pop', 'pop', 'event');
    var compile = angular.copy(tooltip.compile);
    tooltip.compile = function (element, attrs) {
      var first = true;
      attrs.$observe('popShow', function (val) {
        if (JSON.parse(!first || val || false)) {
          $timeout(function () {
            element.triggerHandler('event');
          });
        }
        first = false;
      });
      return compile(element, attrs);
    };
    return tooltip;
  });
```

I created a Plunker with an example of how to use this directive:

http://plnkr.co/edit/94ZHgQ?p=preview

Comment: it's a bit confusing... what the first directive does exactly?

Comment: @Agzam it use inside tooltip directive for template popup

Comment: What does the template/popover/popover.html file look like? I cannot get it on plunker... Thanks!