# How to create a popover that listens to custom events

Tags: angularjs, events, angular-ui, popover, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to create a [popover](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/popover) that I can open and close with my custom events. I tried to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23073388/162345) answer and create my custom popover using:

```
.directive( 'myPopover', [ '$tooltip', function ( $tooltip ) {
  return $tooltip( 'myPopover', 'myPopover', 'openTrigger' );
}]);
```

But that didn't work.

I created a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/NZm3gAGSJewLJyRTaee5?p=preview) sample.