# Programmatically open popover in angular-bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, phantomjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

In an angular application using angular-ui-bootstrap, we have some icons which provide some information to the user:

```
<i class="icon-info ng-scope" popover="Popovertext goes here" popover-trigger="mouseenter" popover-append-to-body="false" data-original-title="" title=""></i>
```

I'm using phantomjs to create screenshots of the application, and I need the popover to be visable on the screenshot.

While in the [angular-ui documentation](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/popover) there is nothing mentioned about showing a popover programmatically, I found a section in the [bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers-options) which mentioned the `popover` method, so I tried:

```
$('.icon-info').popover('show')
```

which is not working (but jQuery is available in the application).

How do I open the popover programmatically (from the context of PhantomJS / browser console)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Open and Close Angular-UI popovers programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23073156/how-to-open-and-close-angular-ui-popovers-programmatically)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple workaround is to manually trigger the event that is used to show it.

Since you are using jQuery this will be enough in your case:

```
$('.icon-info').trigger('mouseenter');
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/J3hwUXA65orsenL2plbY?p=preview